# Membership provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, authorization, membership

What would be the best way to store additional information outside of active directory? I will be utilizing AD authentication as well as WIndowsTokenRoleProvider but I will also need to store some additional information about a user that will be used for authorizations purposes.

This is a ASP.net application with a SQL backend, I am looking for suggestions or perhaps some articles that can provide direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store as much info as you need in the User Profile. There is a default profile provider and you can always write your own if u need something tailored to your needs.

read the part 6 and 7 at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for providing the resource , exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create your own table, then use the ASP.NET Membership ID (make sure you use the GUID, not the username) as a foreign key.